# How to create a numpy _object_ array of other numpy arrays of same and different length?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This is my very first question. So let's see if I can explain exactly what I need.

I am given a python `list` of numpy arrays which can or cannot have different lengths (in one dimension only but this is not important here), e.g.

```
my_list = [
    np.ones((20, 3, 3)),
    np.ones(( 1, 3, 3)),
    np.ones((20, 3, 3))
]
```

Now when I do

```
wrapped_list = np.array(my_list)
```

I get an object of the following structure

```
np.array(shape=(3, ), dtype=object)
```

with the initial three arrays as content. This is what I want. Now the problem:

If `my_list` contained sublists of identical length, then I get, e.g.

```
my_list2 = [
    np.ones((20, 3, 3)),
    np.ones((20, 3, 3)),
    np.ones((20, 3, 3))
]

np.array(my_list2)
```

leads to

```
np.array(shape=(3, 20, 3, 3), dtype=np.float64)
```

This is *not*, what I want. I tried specifying the `dtype`, like

```
np.array(my_list, dtype=object)
```

which will cast *all* (sub-)arrays to `dtype=object`.

I think I found a way to go without wrapping at all, but I am curious on how to set the dtype on a np.array without affecting nested numpy arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an empty object arrary first and fill it with my_list, e.g.:

```
wrapped_list = np.empty((3,),dtype=object)
wrapped_list[:] = my_list2
```

Comment: Yes, this does what I want although I tried to put this into a one-liner in a lambda function actually. Is there a way to do that, too?

Comment: The right way to avoid long code is to wrap it in function definition.  Don't try to use `lambda` to combine lines.

Answer (score 0):

Another (dumb) way, that at least has the virtue of being a single expression:

```
wrapped_list = np.array(my_list + [None])[:-1]
```